# Can't compile qemu with yocto

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, qemu, bitbake

I try to compile the rpi-basic-image.

i didn't modified anything, except local.conf and bblayers.conf. The rest is warrio or autogenerated
qemu-base-image builds normal.

```
bitbake qemu -c cleanall; bitbake qemu -f
WARNING: Host distribution "manjaro" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
Loading cache: 100% |################################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01
Loaded 3319 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.42.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "manjaro"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi3"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2.7.1"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "warrior:b58c50811b5151fb7f9980cb99c32df4eebd0b88"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      
meta-networking      
meta-python          = "warrior:f4ccdf2bc3fe4f00778629088baab840c868e36b"
meta-raspberrypi     = "warrior:0750d5d2bc9596f35d5d61bb0ff657be4b02bfdc"

WARNING: Your host glibc verson (2.30) is newer than that in uninative (2.29). Disabling uninative so that sstate is not corrupted.
```

The error log of bitbake can be found here:
https://termbin.com/edlv

Answer (score 1):

You need the new uninative.  poky commit 1153a954e652304b6b5d287437817b7da891d491 or use the warrior branch.